# Is there a way in which I can iterate over a dictionary and use it in a while loop?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, for-loop, while-loop

This is how my code looks in python. in the line where df = get_data_df(id,start_at) , instead of defining id one by one, I would like for my program to iterate over id and use it in the program below. please help me with how to iterate over the dictionary (id) and use it in the while loop.

```
id= {'O': 6232,
'S': 5819,
'S': 5759,
'R': 6056,
'M': 6145,}

whole_df = pd.DataFrame()
start_at = int(datetime(2020,8,1,6,0,0,0, pytz.UTC).timestamp() * 1e6)
while True:
    df = get_data_df(id,start_at)    
    if df.shape[0] <= 1:
        break
    else:
        whole_df = whole_df.append(df)
        last_timestamp = whole_df.last_valid_index().timestamp()
        start_at = int(last_timestamp * 1e6)
#print(whole_df)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for key in id:
      print(key)
```

Is one way you could do it. Or you Could do it this way

```
i = 0
while True:
    list(id)[i]
    i += 1
```

By Just itterating a index and grabbing a value at each point from that Index

Comment: Thanks. While i run it in my code, the error is 'dict_values' object is not subscriptable.

Comment: Sorry about that Edited my answer to the solution just tested it

Answer (score 0):

There a multiple ways of iterating over a python dictionary using a for loop:

```py
for key in your_dict:
    value = your_dict[key]
    print(value)
```

```py
for value in your_dict.values():
    print(value)
```

```py
for key, value in your_dict.items():
    print(key, '=', value)
```

If you realy want a while loop:

```
keys = your_dict.keys()
i = 0
while i < len(keys):
    value = your_dict[keys[i]]
    print(key, '=', value)
```